# Material-UI Left Drawer in App Bar won't close on overlay click or menu item click in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having an issue I can't seem to pin down where my LeftDrawer for my App Bar isn't closing if I click a menu item or the overlay (Not sure if this is an option, or possible with react components).  Ideally, I would like both options to close the Drawer.  Thank you in advance for taking your time to look at this!

This is my Navbar class I am using to toggle open the LeftDrawer:

```
// Dependencies
import React from 'react';

//Comonents
import LeftDrawer from './left-drawer.jsx';

// Styles
import './nav-bar.scss';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  toggleDrawer(){
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='nav-bar'>
        <AppBar title='My App' onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={() => this.toggleDrawer()}/>
        <LeftDrawer open={this.state.open} onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

This is the LeftDrawer class with the MenuItems:

```
// Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// Styles
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

export default class LeftDrawer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
}

handleToggle() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
}

handleClose() {
    this.setState({open: false});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Drawer
                docked={false}
                width={200}
                open={this.props.open}
                onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
            >
                <Link to="/home"><MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose.bind(this)}>Home</MenuItem></Link>
                <Link to="/topics"><MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose.bind(this)}>404</MenuItem></Link>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reason is you are controlling the Drawer by `props` values (`state` value of parent component) so you need to update the parent `state` value by calling a function from child.

Define a handleClose function in parent:

```
handleClose() {
    this.setState({open: false})
}
```

pass this function to `LeftDrawer` component:

```
<LeftDrawer open={this.state.open} handleClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)} onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} />
```

Then inside child handleClose function call that parent handleClose function:

```
handleClose() {
    this.props.handleClose();
}
```

Full Code:

```
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.toggleDrawer = this.toggleDrawer.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  toggleDrawer(){
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  handleClose(){
    this.setState({open: false})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='nav-bar'>
        <AppBar title='My App' onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer}/>
        <LeftDrawer open={this.state.open} handleClose={this.handleClose} onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class LeftDrawer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {open: false};
      this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggle() {
      this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  }

  handleClose() {
     this.props.handleClose();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Drawer
                docked={false}
                width={200}
                open={this.props.open}
                onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
            >
                <Link to="/home"><MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Home</MenuItem></Link>
                <Link to="/topics"><MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>404</MenuItem></Link>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yup, that was it to fix the MenuItem issue, thank you very much!  Would you have any thought as to how to have to overlay click close the menu also?  Also will mark as answer when the time is up

Comment: Ahhh nevermind I was doing the same setting the open state in the requestChange method, changed to handleClose() and that worked as well.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The `LeftDrawer` component inside `NavBar` contains `onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer}` prop which is not used inside `LeftDrawer`.

Also, seems that `handleToggle` is unnecessary in the inner component, which should manage the state of the parent.

If anyone lands at this question after some time better read about [lifting up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), rather than taking the responses.